# Flow error: unable to parse field as dataType

Tags: error, flow

I'm repeatedly getting the following error in my flow, which is supposed to lookup matching FeedItems, then delete them:

> An error occurred at element Find_Matching_Posts (FlowRecordLookup).
>   unable to parse field as dataType could not be retrieved for the
>   passed field: RawFieldImpl[tableName: FeedItem, columnName:
>   CreatedById__NotFound]

It looks like this might be an SFDC bug, [as listed here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Xn7AAE), but wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong.

Here's my flow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's a headless flow that errors seemingly every time (though it did process correctly at least once). Any ideas? Is this just a bug, or am I doing something wrong?